# Will a fresh installation of Ubuntu recognize two drives that have been in a RAID?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

I have a computer with three hard drives - one is the boot drive and the other two are in RAID1. The RAID is software RAID created during the Ubuntu installation. If I reformat and reinstall Ubuntu on the boot drive will it recognize the two RAID drives as being a RAID or will I have to reconfigure them back into a RAID? If I have to recreate the RAID1 array will have to reformat the drives and lose the data on them?

Basically I may have to do a fresh install of Ubuntu on my boot drive and I do not want to lose the data on my RAID.

Comment: What kind of RAID system are you talking about? Hardware RAID? Fake RAID by your motherboard chipset vendor? Software RAID (which one)?

Comment: Software RAID set up during the Ubuntu install, which I assume is the same as using mdadm.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that info. It's highly relevant to the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced this predicament once. I took the gamble and formatted my boot drive. Later on i realized that [mdadm](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm) can **assemble** the RAID arrays even after a clean installation. What this means is, you dont need to re-configure the RAID once again. mdadm does it and the RAID device would be active for the system.

Run `sudo fdisk -l`. This will list the RAID device, something like `/dev/md0`

Then run `sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0` and you are done.

Check if it worked by running 
`cat /proc/mdstat`

If `fdisk` doesnt output any RAID device, you can run `sudo mdadm --assemble --scan` to automatically detect and assemble the RAID

***The above instruction assumes that you boot from a completely different drive and the RAID is just a media storage***

Comment: Ok cool, it sounds like I will have to do this. So I can run mdadm --assemble without specifying the drives (like /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb2)? Ubuntu will detect thay they are meant to be in a RAID and will automatically assemble them into /dev/md0?

Comment: Once /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb2 are configured as a raid, they are not valid any more individually. I would suggest, you better run `sudo mdadm --assemble --scan`. This should take care automatically.

Comment: So to confirm, I can run 'sudo mdadm --assemble --scan' and then update my fstab so it will be automatically mounted?

Comment: Yes, Exactly. :)