# Downgrade to 14.04.5 without losing RAID 10 data

Tags: system-installation, raid, mdadm, downgrade

I currently have 16.04.1 installed but due to incompatibility with freepbx, I need to downgrade back to 14.04.

The problem is that I have a RAID 10 drive that I can't lose any data off of, and backing up the 9tb of data on the drives isn't feasible right now. The OS is not on the RAID 10, but its own hard drive.

Does anyone have any tips on how I can reinstall without losing any data on the RAID drive? I'm not that experienced with RAID drives and don't want any surprises.

Edit to answer questions:
I have one 500gb system drive at sda1
A raid 10 array made out of sd-b c d e.

I found this [Will a fresh installation of Ubuntu recognize two drives that have been in a RAID?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549320/will-a-fresh-installation-of-ubuntu-recognize-two-drives-that-have-been-in-a-rai?rq=1) so felt comfortable doing the downgrade. I did the steps on it, mainly mdadm --assemble --scan. Now I have /dev/md0, but it's not seeing a partition. Please help!

fdisk -l is telling me:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 5001.0 GB, 5000981078016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 608001 cylinders, total 9767541168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT 
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
```

and at the bottom

```
Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Comment: I've no idea how to downgrade the system, but perhaps would it make sense to just downgrade specific packages causing problems to freepbx?

Comment: How many drives do you have connected in your RAID setup? (>4)

Comment: First: If you don't have a second RAID set or something else to hold at least another copy of your data you are already risking your data right now. Consider your data lost right now. Your statement that it's not feasible to have a backup is outright silly. Redundancy is not a backup. Second: Was your initial setup of the RAID created with mdadm (that should be easy to reassemble unless followed instructions to setup a configuration that has to be remembered), was it controller based, filesystem based (zfs, btrfs, lvm)?

Comment: it won't let me edit my post, but I got it! I was using the wrong file system when trying to mount! All is well now!